# List ports a process PID is listening on (preferably using iproute2 tools)?

Tags: ip, monitoring, port-forwarding, iproute

I'm looking to list all ports a PID is currently listening on.

How would you recommend I get this kind of data about a process?

Comment: Weird enough `ss` has no filtering on PID except for netlink sockets.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use `ss` from the iproute2 package (which is similar to `netstat`):

```
ss -l -p -n | grep "pid=1234,"
```

or (for older iproute2 version):

```
ss -l -p -n | grep ",1234,"
```

Replace 1234 with the PID of the program.

Comment: There is also `-u` or `-t` for udb or tcp only. :+1: And these can all be stacked like so: `ss -tlnp`, And to eliminate fill width output, which [I find annoying](http://superuser.com/q/983076/309066) you can pipe though cat or less or w/e: `ss -tlnp | cat`

Comment: I've gotten into the habit `ss -nlp | cat`, that's roughly, show me listening processes (-l), their port numbers (-n), and their process info (-p), and don't try to fit the output to my shell `| cat` (or less or whatever). Only took me two years to get used to that :D

Comment: Didn't work for me (on Debian 9). There you need to grep for ",pid=1234,"

Comment: @ofrommel thanks for the hint - I adapted the answer.

Comment: Also, this does only work with root permissions :)

Comment: i run with sudo and process is blank

Answer (score 76):

I am not aware of a way using `iproute2` tools. But as a workaround, you could try this one out.

```
lsof -Pan -p PID -i
```

should give you the information you are looking for.

---

**Output**

```
lsof -Pan -p 27808 -i
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   27808 apache    5u  IPv6 112811294      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd   27808 apache    7u  IPv6 112811298      0t0  TCP *:8443 (LISTEN)
httpd   27808 apache    9u  IPv6 112811303      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

I got this command from [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com) but not sure of the exact link since I have all of them noted down in the notebook. But you could check out from there as well.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `netstat` for this to figure out pid of each listen process.

netstat - Print network connections, routing tables, interface statistics, masquerade connections, and multicast memberships

-a, --all
       Show both listening and non-listening (for TCP this means established connections) sockets.  With the --interfaces option, show interfaces  that  are  not marked

--numeric , -n
       Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names.

-p, --program
       Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.

Here is an example:

```
# netstat -anp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1507/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51188               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1651/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1013                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1680/ypbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1975/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1763/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2081/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2119/mongod
tcp        0     48 172.16.33.73:22             172.16.127.110:51850        ESTABLISHED 25473/sshd
tcp        0      0 172.16.33.73:22             172.16.127.110:51214        ESTABLISHED 24699/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      1507/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 :::9200                     :::*                        LISTEN      1994/java
tcp        0      0 :::9300                     :::*                        LISTEN      1994/java
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1975/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN      1763/cupsd
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      2081/master
tcp        0      0 :::59162                    :::*                        LISTEN      1651/rpc.statd
```

Comment: Thank you though I've been informed that `netstat` has been deprecated by iproute2 tools and I'm looking to avoid it.

Answer (score 13):

[@jofel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157826/7453) shows you the appropriate tool to use, `ss`, here's the replacements for the other networking tools in iproute2.

The deprecated commands and their iproute2 equivalents are as follows:

```
deprecated      replacement(s)
==========      ==============
- arp           ip n (ip neighbor)
- ifconfig      ip a (ip addr), ip link, ip -s (ip -stats)
- iptunnel      ip tunnel
- iwconfig      iw
- nameif        ip link, ifrename
- netstat       ss, ip route (for netstat-r), ip -s link (for netstat -i), 
                ip maddr (for netstat-g)

- route         ip r (ip route)
```

The basic list is also here on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2.

#### References

- [Deprecated Linux networking commands and their replacements](http://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/)

Answer (score 2):

Another method for `lsof` if you don't know the PID, but just the name of the Program:

```
lsof -Pa -p $(pgrep [programName]) -i
```

Comment: doesn't work with `lsof` 4.89 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: That will be the case if the program has spawned multiple processes.which in that case you will need to specify the specific PID when running the lsof command I gave.

`pgrep <program name>` then choose the PID you need for the above command. replacing `$(pgrep [programName])` with the PID#

Comment: lsof -Pan -c programName -i

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried, this also does same

```
netstat -plnt | grep 27071
```

[image: success]

Answer (score 0):

If 1072 is the process id, then you can run:

1. `sudo netstat -nlp | grep -w "1072"`

   ```shellsession
   $ sudo netstat -nlp | grep -w "1072"
   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address    State      
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5060       0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      1072/your_process_name  
   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5060       0.0.0.0:*                   1072/your_process_name
   ```

   or
2. `sudo ss -lnp | grep -w "pid=1072"`

   ```shellsession
   $ sudo ss -lnp | grep -w "pid=1072"
   udp    UNCONN     0      0         *:5060   *:*   users:(("your_process_name",pid=1072,fd=40))
   tcp    LISTEN     0      1023      *:5060   *:*   users:(("your_process_name",pid=1072,fd=44))
   ```

Process name: `your_process_name`
Process ID: `1072`
Port number: `5060`

#### Note (docker or kubernetes):

If you running the above command inside a docker/kubernetes container, then the process id and the process name *may not* be shown in the output of `ss` or `netstat` command due to insufficient privileges. You can use `SYS_PTRACE` [linux capability](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) inside your Docker container as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61014093) or in your Kubernetes spec file as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64294738).

However, you should NOT use `SYS_PTRACE` in **production**, since `SYS_PTRACE` can be abused to gain root access via privilege escalation  as mentioned [here](https://blog.pentesteracademy.com/privilege-escalation-by-abusing-sys-ptrace-linux-capability-f6e6ad2a59cc).