# Finding the PORT NUMBER of the process using a specific PID?

Tags: linux, process, syslog, rsyslog

I have a specific PID and my question is how can I know which port belongs to that PID.
Any tips on how to know the port of a service that has a specific PID?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use [ss](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157826/414186) or [lsof](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157824/414186)

Answer (score 0):

One can use lsof with the -i (only list IPv4/6), -P (no port names), and -n (no hostnames) arguments, and then grep the PID:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep <PID>
```

This will present you with all ports the service might be using.